# command to capture exit status of last background process in bash

Tags: linux, bash

i need  exit status of last background task completed.so that i can judge if it is failed or passed.
I do this .

```
#!bin/sh
task1 &
task2

echo $? # give the exit status of last command
```

1. how to get the exit status of task1.
2. do i need to keep wait command after task2 ?

Comment: better approach is to use `SIGCHLD`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't get the exit status of the background command unless you call `wait` to wait for it to finish. The exit code from `wait` is the exit code of the background task, so if you check `wait`'s exit code that'll be the value you want.

```
task1 &
task2

wait    
echo $?
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this so that the wait itself runs in the background, without getting "pid XXX is not a child of this shell" error?

Comment: I recommend asking that as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Wait does not return the status of task1. If you need the status you will have to specify the pid of the task1.