# Get return value of command run in background with pipe and tee command

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to get the return value of command run in background with pipe so i have below sample code.

```
#!/bin/bash

export RETVALUE="0"
CMD='ls ThisFileDoesNotExit'
LOG='tee -a log.txt'
$CMD | $LOG ; RETVALUE=${PIPESTATUS[0]} &
#$CMD | $LOG ; echo ${PIPESTATUS[0]} & // This print ret value 2
wait
echo "Return Value of ls is $RETVALUE"
```

**Output:**

```
Return Value of ls is 0 // It should print value 2
```

**If i echo the return value from same command then it print correct return value.**

**But if store it in RETVALUE  variable then it shows wrong value.**

Comment: This? [shell - get exit code of background process](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1570356/1983854). That is, `$!`

Comment: you are storing it into a variable already: RETVALUE.  There is nothing that will keep you from assigning that variable's value to another `var=$RETVALUE`

Comment: @SaintHax By assigning this way, $RETVALUE always print "0" while error return value  is 2. Please see updated question.

Comment: @fedorqui $! will return the pid of forked process. I need to return value of 1st process in pipe command. And i can get that value by echo but not by storing in RETVALUE variable.

Comment: [Don't store commands in variables.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [command to capture exit status of last background process in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20257935/command-to-capture-exit-status-of-last-background-process-in-bash)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is due to the & sign. This puts the RETVALUE assignment into the background, thus this command executes in a different environment than the current script, so the variables in your script do no get updated.

You also don't need to export the RETVALUE.
Also the `wait` command is not necessary, as bash does not process the next command until it has finished the previous one (unless you use the & to put it in the background)

```
#!/bin/bash

RETVALUE="0"
CMD='ls ThisFileDoesNotExit'
LOG='tee -a log.txt'
$CMD | $LOG
RETVALUE=${PIPESTATUS[0]}
echo "Return Value of ls is $RETVALUE"
```

EDIT: If you need to launch the process in the background, you will be forced to create a new script in order to recover the PIPESTATUS value, due to this variable is volatile. A possible solution is:

```
#!/bin/bash

CMD='ls ThisFileDoesNotExit'
LOG='tee -a log.txt'
TMPSCRIPT="file1.sh"
echo '#!/bin/bash' > $TMPSCRIPT
echo "$CMD |$LOG" >> $TMPSCRIPT
echo 'exit ${PIPESTATUS[0]}' >> $TMPSCRIPT
chmod +x $TMPSCRIPT
./$TMPSCRIPT &
MYPID=$!
wait $MYPID
RETVALUE=$?
rm $TMPSCRIPT
echo "Return Value of ls is $RETVALUE"
```

Comment: I need to run whole commnad in background only so i have put &  . Without & its work fine but i need to do the same for background

Comment: Yes man...it works as i wanted... let me look for any other solution if possible then. Otherwise i will accept your answer.

Comment: It's simpler to wrap the command in a function that to write out a temporary script: `tmp_func () { command | tee -a log.txt; return ${PIPESTATUS[0]}; }`, then run the *function* in the background to eventually `wait` on it.